# Winter bash 2015

Tags: discussion

Even if I know the answer, I'm obligated to add this question in here:
Should we join the [Winter Bash 2015](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/)?
Answer below with Yey or Ney.

**[Update]**
Since this was unanimous, starting Dec 14th we will have awesome hats till Jan 3rd. Wear them responsibly.

Answer (score 10):

Yay! woohoo!

.. sorry "Yey"

Answer (score 7):

Yey!

***//bodyMustBeAtLeast30Characters***

Comment: I found a way around it ;)

Comment: @philwinkle. Nice "way around". Now I can post empty answers just to screw with people's heads :)

Answer (score 5):

Yey.

Comment: Haha, nice answer :)

Comment: Ha ha you are totally a Ninja :)

Answer (score 2):

Yey

Comment: Yeyy............

Answer (score 2):

Yeyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.............

Answer (score 2):

Yey

Answer (score 1):

Yey ... :)

//#whyotheranswerslessthan30isaccepted?

Comment: <!--click edit on the short answers-->

Comment: @Marius, got it.

Answer (score 1):

Yey.

Comment: Check their posts ("Edit"). There you'll find the answer.

Comment: Haha @AnnaVölkl, Thanks for the trick but it is cheating :p

Comment: Sure it is. But for the sake of this question it's ok I think ;)

Comment: Yes when it comes to Mauris everything must be ok :P